# horizontal correlation across variables in R data frame

Tags: r, correlation, recommendation-engine

I want to calculation a correlation score between two sets of numbers, but these numbers are within each row

The background is that I'm compiling a recommender system, using PCA to give me scores for each user and each item to each derived feature (1,2,3 in this case)

```
user item user_score_1 user_score_2 user_score_3 item_score_1 item_score_2 item_score_3
 A     1       0.5          0.6         -0.2          0.2          0.8         -0.3
 A     2       0.5          0.6         -0.2          0.4          0.1         -0.8
 A     3       0.5          0.6         -0.2         -0.2         -0.4         -0.1
 B     1      -0.6         -0.1          0.9          0.2          0.8         -0.3
 B     2      -0.6         -0.1          0.9          0.4          0.1         -0.8
 B     3      -0.6         -0.1          0.9         -0.2         -0.4         -0.1
```

I've combined the outputs for each user and item into this all x all table.  For each row in this table, I need to calculate the correlation between user scores 1,2,3 & item scores 1,2,3 (e.g. for the first row what is the correlation between 0.5,0.6,-0.2 and 0.2,0.8,-0.3) to see how well the user and the item match.

The other alternative would be to the correlation before I join the users & items into an all x all dataset, but I'm not sure how to do that best either.

I don't think I can transpose the table as in reality the users and items total is very large.

Any thoughts on a good approach?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: not the most efficient but you could try `users <- t(dat[,3:5]); items <- t(dat[,6:8]); Vectorize(cor)(x=split(users, col(users)), y=split(items, col(items)))`

Comment: Thanks, this looks to have worked!

Comment: The only thing to add was that I was working in a data.table so needed to use a data.frame instead...

Comment: If you wanted to stay with the data table, you might try  `scoresDT[, cor(c(user_score_1,user_score_2,user_score_3), 
               c(item_score_1,item_score_2,item_score_3)),
         by= .(user, item)]` where `scoresDT` is your data table.

Comment: This works well actually as it doesn't require me to create quite large user/item data.  The only trouble I'm having with this is using a dynamic list of variable names when instructing it what to use in the correlation.  i.e. where it has cor(c(user_score_1...etc I'd want to be able to tell it a list of variables to use instead, but I get the 'x' must be numeric error when trying this...  Any thoughts?